# How can I see the OpenJML error messages?

Tags: java, eclipse, openjml

When I run my code with the OpenJML test in eclipse. I get this output ......

Skipping long-running tests
5 system specification classes found for esc testing
JRE version 1.8.0_202
5 system specification classes found for rac testing
TEST: testParseAndCheckCrash

TEST: testParseAndCheckCrash2

java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundles(InternalPlatform.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getBundle(InternalPlatform.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.getBundle(Platform.java:1424)
    at org.jmlspecs.openjml.JmlSpecs.appendInternalSpecs(JmlSpecs.java:351)
    at org.jmlspecs.openjml.JmlSpecs.setSpecsPath(JmlSpecs.java:459)
    at org.jmlspecs.openjml.JmlSpecs.setSpecsPath(JmlSpecs.java:415)
    at org.jmlspecs.openjml.JmlSpecs.initializeSpecsPath(JmlSpecs.java:273)
    at org.jmlspecs.openjml.Main.setupOptions(Main.java:962)
    at org.jmlspecs.openjml.Main.processArgs(Main.java:1017)

What am I doing wrong, I am looking for the test to tell me what is wrong with my code and which line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OpenJML is not properly installed verifies or redo the installation by repeating each step. 
Check all the Paths and if there is still a problem, 
I can only advise you to go see the official documentation